# Are there any quartz crystal-based data storage devices?

Tags: data-storage

Some time ago I've read about [5D 'Superman memory crystal' heralds unlimited lifetime data storage](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/jul/17/5d-superman-memory-crystal-heralds-unlimited-lifetime-data-storage) which is about the data-storage technique which uses a laser to alter the optical properties of fused quartz at the nanoscale.

This kind of devices can potentially store 360TB of data (equivalent to 75,000 DVDs) on a standard-sized disc.

Is this technology real so far? Are there any available hardware devices for data storage based on that technology that you can recommend?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for technical explanations, not for recommendations (except for a bolted-on too-broad addendum — as a recommendation it's lacking price points, capacity requirements, performance requirements, …).

Comment: It is a an interesting question, but not particularly about modern computer hardware, and is way to broad. Again, an interesting question, but off-topic.

Comment: How would I know if it's not about modern hardware without asking? The article is few years old.

Comment: After reflection, and based on [meta](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4/are-what-should-i-consider-when-buying-questions-allowed) [discussions](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/139/is-a-scope-of-product-recommendations-pre-purchase-inquiries-agreeable), I've voted to reopen. The answer is probably that there's still more marketing hype than technology at this point, and you should come back in a decade or two, but that should be an answer (if it's true), it isn't a reason to close.

Comment: @Gilles Seconded. At a glance, the recommendation part seems broad, but then again the technology in question isn't exactly a broad topic itself, so a recommendation without parameters is acceptable.